# Sequelize - Model Property Setter Method Not Working

Tags: sequelize.js

I am have a column within my table that is going to use a hashing module to hash (characters & integers) the auto-incrementing primary key on the table. I have tried using the `get` and `set` methods for the hashing schema property to achieve just this, but the value is never being set.

```js
 var Hashids = require('hashids');
 var hashids = new Hashids('blog', 10);
 
 var blogComment = sequelize.define('blog_comment', {
     blogCommentId: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         field: 'blog_comment_id',
         autoIncrement: true,
         primaryKey: true
     },
     blogCommentIdHash: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING,
         field: 'blog_comment_id_hash',
         get: function(){
             var blogCommentId = this.getDataValue('blogCommentId');
             return this.setDataValue('blogCommentIdHash', hashids.encode(blogCommentId));
         }
     }, 
 
 ...
 
 }
```

I have also tried a different setup where I attach a `set` method to id property with similar functionality, but still no success.

```js
 var Hashids = require('hashids');
     var hashids = new Hashids('blog', 10);
     
     var blogComment = sequelize.define('blog_comment', {
         blogCommentId: {
             type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
             field: 'blog_comment_id',
             autoIncrement: true,
             primaryKey: true,
             set: function(val){
               return this.setDataValue('blogCommentIdHash', hashids.encode(val));
             }
         },
         blogCommentIdHash: {
             type: DataTypes.STRING,
             field: 'blog_comment_id_hash'
         }, 
     
     ...
     
     }
```

What am I doing wrong with these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sequelize getter and setters you need to use the following syntax:

```js
 clientStartDate:{
         type: Sequelize.DATE,
         allowNull: false,
         validate:{
             isDate: true,
             isAfter: "6/24/2018"
         },
         get(){
             this.getDataValue('clientStartDate');
         },
         set(date){
             //set date so it's value only contains a Date and No Time
             console.log("DATE: "+ date);
             date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
             this.setDataValue("clientStartDate",date);
         }
```

Notice how I have parenthesis after the function names, ie: get() and set(parameter). In setter functions you also don't need to return the value of setDataValue(). Also don't make the mistake of using this.getDataValue('property_name') to retrieve a value in a setter function, as the original value hasn't been assigned to that property_name before your model calls the set() function. Always retrieve the value you are trying to manipulate through the set() parameter.

I would also look into using the other form of implementing getter/setter methods in Models (As shown from the documentation):

```js
 const Foo = sequelize.define('foo', {
   firstname: Sequelize.STRING,
   lastname: Sequelize.STRING
   }, {
   getterMethods: {
     fullName() {
       return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
     }
   },

   setterMethods: {
     fullName(value) {
       const names = value.split(' ');

       this.setDataValue('firstname', names.slice(0, -1).join(' '));
       this.setDataValue('lastname', names.slice(-1).join(' '));
     },
   }
 });
```

Comment: in javascript
`{ set: function(val){ /*...*/ } }`
is equivalent to ...
`{ set(val){ /*...*/ } }`
so it seems unlikely that is the problem

And the questioner doesn't use `getDataValue` inside a setter function so it seems unlikely that that is the problem either